# error Database connection failure: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

hay, i have docker-compose and install container for odoo 12, this is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
    version: '3.3'

services:

  odoo12:
    image: odoo:12.0
    container_name: odoo12
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db12-odoo
    ports: 
      - 8013:8069
    volumes: 
      - odoo12-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons

  db12-odoo:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db12-odoo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 9091:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo12
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo12
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres12 
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
    - odoo12-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

  pgadmin12-demo:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin12
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: odoo12@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 7778:80
    volumes:
      - pgadmin12-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    depends_on:
      - db12-odoo

      
volumes:
  odoo12-web-data:
  odoo12-db-data: 
  pgadmin12-data:
```

all service is running , but just service **odoo12** is not running, when i access **localhost:8013** in browser is error, and when i see logs service odoo12 , error like this:

```
Database connection failure: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

whats wrong with my config ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database has a DNS name `db12-odoo` not `db`. Either change config of your application so that it connects to `db12-odoo` or change name of the service:

```yaml
  db: # it was called 'db12-odoo' previously
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db12-odoo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 9091:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo12
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo12
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres12 
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
    - odoo12-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

You can also add a network alias instead of changing service name:

```yaml
  db12-odoo:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db12-odoo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - 9091:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo12
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo12
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres12 
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
    - odoo12-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
            - db
```

Comment: i have difference 2 file docker-compose , for odoo12 and odoo14, in odoo14 docker-compose file services called name db, in odoo12 called db12-odoo

Comment: and its other version of postgres ineach docker-compose file

Comment: @bimoan I don't see how that can make a problem if those two are on different networks. In any case you still can make `odoo12` to look for `db12-odoo` hostname instead of `db`. Add `HOST=db12-odoo` environment variable to your `odoo12` service.

Comment: You can give all of these things simple names (for example, name the database `db`) and delete the `container_name:`.  So long as the two versions are in directories with different names, Compose will assign its own name to each and there won't be a conflict.

Comment: hay ! its works after i delete all docker images and volumes,, and i also add environment HOST in odoo12. Thanks

Comment: @bimoan glad to help. Mind David's comment above, that's also an option. If you are not going to wait for additional answers - please accept this one so that the question won't remain unanswered.